# Como mostro o resultado de uma query SQLSRV em PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server

Preciso fazer um cálculo via sqlsrv, somar um coluna de valores.

Este é o código que tentei fazer:

```
$qryAC = "SELECT SUM(VLRECEITACONT) AS receitaConta
          FROM [RDO].[dbo].[ANALISE_CRITICA]
          WHERE CC='$partCC[$i]' ";

$stmtAC = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $qryAC );
echo $stmtAC;
```

Como faço para exibir o resultado desta query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depois de transformar o texto contido em `$qryAC` em uma consulta é necessário pegar o seu retorno com [sqlsrv_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) ou similar.

```
$stmtAC = sqlsrv_query($conn, $qryAC);

while( $item = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmtAC, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
      echo $item['receitaConta']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: Valeu perdeu! Deu certo.